# how to Pass a value via href without error

Tags: php, html

I am passing a value using the Href tag like this :

```
<a href="myPage.php?var=<?php echo $somthing ?>"></a>
```

in the second page (myPage.php) :

```
echo $_GET['var'];
```

but an error message appear :

> Undefined index: var

Any solutions please

Comment: make sure the HREF has ?var and also make sure $something has value. Make `var_dump($something);` to see its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if `$_GET['var']` is set or not using:

```
isset($_GET['var'])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes thank you, i solved the problem with a `<form>` tag and then using '<button type="submit" value="<?php echo $somthing; ?>" />` to get the value